# How many episodes of Naruto are there?

Tags: naruto

I have been watching Naruto online, and there are no episodes available to watch after 301, even though I know there is a big war on that episode. Are there any more Naruto episodes? People have been saying there is an episode 700, but is that all manga?

Comment: There is Naruto 220 episode and Naruto Shippuden is still airing has more that 400 episode. The manga ended at chapter 700 and after that till now there are 700+10 manga know as __Naruto Gaiden: The Seventh Hokage__

Comment: Do you know any websites I can find all the episodes on?

Comment: [anime-planet](http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/naruto-shippuden/videos) but i am not sure you will get to watch all episode ,they may charge you , they may not ,but most of the episode are free to watch.

Comment: And [here](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/923/6345) are some site that stream anime

Comment: @mirroroftruth you might consider adding that as an actual answer. I think it addresses everything pretty clearly.

Comment: @Narutorules I think you're looking for English dubbed episodes. As far as I know, English dubbed versions are not available after episode 300. It's time you have to switch to English subbed episodes.

Comment: 220 episodes for Naruto original series, 500 episodes for Naruto shippuden series and 5 Boruto: Naruto next generation

Answer (score 8):

There are [220 episodes](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=anime&aid=239) in Naruto original anime series, which has been completed. Then Naruto Shippuden, which has 500 episodes in total. The series finished airing on the 23rd of March, 2017.

You can stream and watch anime from [anime-planet](http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/naruto-shippuden/videos) or [some other anime streaming sites](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/922/how-can-i-tell-if-a-site-is-legal/923#923). Some of them may charge you, some of them may not. Best way to watch Shippuden is on Crunchy Roll.

There are 700 manga chapters and an extra 10 chapters in the Naruto: The Seventh Hokage and the Scarlet manga, which is set several years ahead of the final chapter (volume 72) of Naruto.

With the conclusion of Naruto, we now have its spin-off/sequel, Boruto: Naruto Next Generations. This is currently airing on Crunchy Roll and is 18 canon episodes in as I am writing this. Also the manga is available to read for all the purists.

Comment: well nowhere near 700 episodes is a bit exaggerated. I mean there are in total 639 episodes of naruto. 220 naruto + 419 naruto shippuden

Answer (score 3):

For a question with ~60k views, I found this to be surprisingly un-updated. Community bumped it up in my feed and I decided to answer.

Naruto the Anime, as it is defined includes 2 series, 11 movies and over a dozen OVAs. The full list is available here [List of Animated Naruto Media](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Animated_Media)

The first Naruto anime adaptation premiered in Japan on TV Tokyo October 3, 2002, and ran for **220 episodes** until its conclusion on February 8, 2007. It led to a first timeskip of two years. 3 movies were also released with the original Anime.

Naruto: Shippuden is the sequel to the original Naruto anime and covers the Naruto manga from volume 28 on. The TV adaptation of Naruto: Shippuden debuted in Japan on February 15, 2007, on TV Tokyo, and concluded on March 23, 2017. The series ran for a total of **500 Episodes**. There were another 8 movies accompanying the series, the last of which set stage for Naruto's son's solo series, **Boruto:The Next Generations** which is currently airing. (**5 Episodes** and counting).

Thus, there is no Episode 700 since the Original run and Shippuden are seperate series. Total episode count of Naruto finished at **720 Episodes**. Boruto is not considered to be of the same continuity because Kishimato is no longer writing the series but is more of a supervisor.

Answer (score 2):

You must be following the Naruto Shippuden English Dub Episodes. At the moment, the English Dub episodes are lagging far behind the Japanese episodes as far as the anime is concerned. Like @mirroroftruth said, the Manga is the latest episode.

But in English Dub, the latest is episode 301 and more are coming up. The next one is expected to be aired on July 11th. So you'll have to be patient.

As for Japanese, the latest one aired yet is episode 418.

Answer (score 0):

Now that the Shippuden has finally ended, I can say for certain that...

Original Naruto series has 220 episodes.

Naruto Shippuden has exactly 500 episodes.

Not to mention like 40% of [Naruto](http://www.animefillerlist.com/shows/naruto) and [Naruto Shippuden](http://www.animefillerlist.com/shows/naruto-shippuden) is fillers.